# git-grep --ignore-case и кириллица

Tags: linux, git, unicode, grep

Пытаюсь найти в проекте все вхождения русской строки без учёта регистра. Например, слово "линукс". Вызываю

```
git grep -i 'линукс'
```

Он находит все вхождения "линукс", но не "Линукс" или "ЛИНУКС". В то же время обычный grep находит:

```
grep -r -i 'линукс' .
```

**Вопрос:** В чём может быть причина? Это баг git-grep?

---

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Git version: 2.7.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

похоже, что ошибку [исправили в 2.10.0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a883c31af66195556a775f75851f46573c98e43d):

> "git grep -i" has been taught to fold case in non-ascii locales
>   correctly.

---

ставьте вручную [версию 2.14](https://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/). в ней эта ошибка уже не воспроизводится:

> `$ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:16.04 bash -c '{ apt update && apt install -y wget && wget https://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git{_2.14.1-1ubuntu4_amd64,-man_2.14.1-1ubuntu4.1_all}.deb && { dpkg -i *.deb; apt -y -f install; } && git init && echo -e "примус\nПримус" > file && git add file; } &>/dev/null && LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 git grep -i примус'`

```
file:примус  
file:Примус
```